# Google Play Games with Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have an Android App up and running using Google Play Services (for real time multiplayer). I would like to use Google App Engine with this project, I was looking at the Youtube video for Google's Mobile Backend Starter. 
When I open the Cloud Console and try to deploy my existing app, this is what shows up:

[image]

So I'm wondering if there is a way to use GAE in my existing app.
Thanks.

Comment: which specific youtube video are you looking at?

Answer (score 0):

The page for the [Mobile Backend Starter](http://cloud.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs) now redirects to [Cloud Endpoints](http://cloud.google.com/endpoints/). There are a few [videos available](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=google+cloud+endpoints) on the subject from Google Developers.